# Error into visual studio pro 2013 - service setup

Tags: c#

I develop a windows service with C# language. Since some day, i have a new error when I want install my service.

> error 1001 installutillib.dll : unknown error

Someone know what is this error ? And maybe say me how can I correct this.

Comment: Check this link. It describes using of this dll and possible ways to fix it: http://www.dlltool.com/articles/2014072103/

Comment: I  have already see this link but I have uninstall and re-install .net framework 4.5.2 and that's change nothing